# Where is the width and height box editor for shapes in Illustrator CS6

Tags: adobe-illustrator, interface-design

Adobe Illustrator CS5 has a box in the toolbar where you can edit the size of a rectangle by inputting the numbers when a shape is selected. Is this still being used in CS6?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AI CS6 has the same boxes in the toolbar (see pink arrows below). You must have a different workspace arrangement, otherwise you should see these with the default workspace.

[image]

Or for smaller laptop screens, which will display a compacted view, you should look for the TRANSFORM link:

[image]

Comment: I can't find anything that will tell me how to get that workspace arrangement on my illustrator :((

Comment: Going to "Main Menu > Window > Workspace > Essentials" should change your screen setup back from whatever it is you are seing now. By the way posting your AI screen might help resolve this.

Comment: Or, are you using AI on a very small screen (13 inches or under)? In this case the boxes might not be displayed because they get hidden for small screens.

Comment: Yes, I'm using a 13" screen. So those options aren't available for smaller screens?

Comment: They probably are, you just need to look somewhere else. There must be an orange TRANSFORM link right about in the same location? If you do see it, click that and here they are. (screenshot added in my answer above, which you can approve by the way :)

Comment: If you're happy with this answer please click the Approve button next to my first screenshot, so i can build up a good profile here :) thanks

Answer (score 2):

That's called the **Control panel** [according to Adobe](https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/workspace-basics.html). Yours has probably been hidden by mistake.

In the menu bar, select `Window` and then ensure there is a check mark beside `Control` in the drop down. If there isn't, select it and the Control panel should then display.

Also, note that the dimensions boxes are context sensitive, so they don't show all the time. They only show when appropriate tools are selected.